# what does this dereference operator in front of function name do?

Tags: function, dereference

I haven't found any mention of this anywhere. There is a dereference operator in a function name like this:

```
char *func()
{
   //code
}
```

what is the purpose of that * operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually dereferencing anything, the `*` is part of the return type.
The compiler doesn't really care about where you place the `*`, so your code is equivalent to writing

```
char* func() { }
```

In other words it means that func() returns a char pointer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll be able to accept your answer in a few minutes

Comment: No problem! For readability, I recommend the `char* func()` way of writing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a dereference operator, applied to the function, but function, returning pointer to a `char`.